# Shipping address custom attribute value not getting in RateRequest object in Carrier Model in magento2.x

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento2.2, custom-attributes

I have added the drop-down custom field on checkout page with custom values.

[image]

**InstallSchema.php**

```
$connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('quote_address'),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table ::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => NULL,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' => 'Mob Type'
                ]
            );
        $connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('sales_order_address'),
                'mob_type',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table ::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'default' => NULL,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' => 'Mob Type'
                ]
            );
        $installer->endSetup();
```

**Plugin**

```
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class MobPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(LayoutProcessor $subject, $jsLayout) {
        $customAttributeCode = 'mob_type';
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                'id' => 'drop-down',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.mob_type',
            'label' => 'Mob Type',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
            'sortOrder' => 150,
            'id' => 'drop-down',
            'options' => [
                [
                    'value' => 'local',
                    'label' => 'Local',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => 'vip',
                    'label' => 'VIP',
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save_custom_field" type="Namespace\CustomModule\Plugin\Checkout\SaveAddressInformation" />
    </type>

</config>
```

**SaveAddressInformation.php**

```
class SaveAddressInformation
{
    protected $quoteRepository;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $shippingAddress = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes = $shippingAddress->getExtensionAttributes();
    if ($shippingAddressExtensionAttributes) {
        $customField = $shippingAddressExtensionAttributes->getMobType();
        $shippingAddress->setMobType($customField);
    }

    }
}
```

But once click on shipping rate of radio button Magento call guest or user API to carrier model, In carrier model all request information passed but my custom attribute values not getting.

-module-offline-shipping\Model\Carrier\Flaterate.php

```
private function getShippingPrice(RateRequest $request, $freeBoxes)
    {
       echo $request->getMobType(); exit; // empty result
        $shippingPrice = false;

        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'O') {
            // per order
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerOrder($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') === 'I') {
            // per item
            $shippingPrice = $this->itemPriceCalculator->getShippingPricePerItem($request, $configPrice, $freeBoxes);
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false && (
                $request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $freeBoxes
            )
        ) {
            $shippingPrice = '0.00';
        }
        return $shippingPrice;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean, when you click "Next" button you lose your custom attribute on shipping address ? Do you have `set-shipping-information-mixin.js` in your module?

Comment: yes. I did it. but I am  not getting me value on request object.

Comment: Did you found solution for this?

Comment: @Magento2Devloper Have you found any solution

Comment: @Ranganathan have you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a specific shipping rate, all fields are not passed to the api call. It only passes the fields specified in the shipping rate validation rules JS.

You can find the file for FlatRate here:

```
vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/view/frontend/web/js/shipping-rate-validation-rules/flatrate.js
```

Override that file and add your field there, that should send it to the shipping rates api call.

Comment: but how can i pass custom attribute in require?

Comment: What do you mean? You need to override the js file and add it to the getRules() function

Comment: I understand but how can I set it? like as getRules: function () {
            return {
                'postcode': {
                    'required': true
                },
                'custom_attributes': {
                    'required': true
                }
            };
        }

Comment: No, you need to use the attribute code `mob_type`.

Comment: did but only four values passed in the address.

Comment: Which four values?

Comment: countryId
:
"US"
postcode
:
"30046"
region
:
""
regionId
:
"19"

Comment: First of all, make sure the changes you made to the JS were actually applied to the frontend. It could be a cache issue, could be you are running older version of the static files etc. Second, make sure the field name in the frontend is mob_type. Third, either debug and check how the code works or use a few different combinations such as custom_attributes: {mob_type:{required:true}} or mob_type or ‘custom_attributes.mob_type or custom_attributes etc

Comment: yes, I checked it and not working. custom attribute not passed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75086/discussion-between-hungersoft-and-magento2-devloper).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, Magento2 is hard coding the fields needed for collecting shipping methods here : `/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address.php` line : `984`

Magento2 design is not flexible [at all] and is over complicated.

Comment: 984 - but this position in how to get address values?

Comment: @Magento2Devloper your comment isn't clear.

Comment: it's means I am not getting custom filed values in address object and not in request object

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem. In the end the only thing that worked for me was to get the POST data and use them to calculate the shipping rate cost. I will really glad to see how it should be done the "magento way"

```
$formpostdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (isset($formpostdata['address']['custom_attributes']['mob_type'])) {
    // add here your logic
}
```

Comment: This one solution is not working in magento2.2.x version getting json_decode error.

Comment: Hi, this works but were you able to find solution in standard magento way? I am facing the same issue like in this post

Answer (score 0):

Flatrate->geShippingPrice() log:

```
[2018-04-01 09:25:48] main.DEBUG: Flatrate->getShippingPrice::Array
(
    [all_items] => Array
        (
            [0 (Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item)] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 134
                    [quote_id] => 138
                    [created_at] => 2018-04-01 09:15:02
                    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                    [product_id] => 3
                    [store_id] => 1
                    [is_virtual] => 0
                    [sku] => test
                    [name] => test
                    [is_qty_decimal] => 
                    [no_discount] => 0
                    [weight] => 0.0000
                    [qty] => 1
                    [price] => 10
                    [base_price] => 10
                    [discount_percent] => 0.0000
                    [discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [base_discount_amount] => 0.0000
                    [tax_percent] => 0
                    [tax_amount] => 0
                    [base_tax_amount] => 0
                    [row_total] => 10
                    [base_row_total] => 10
                    [row_total_with_discount] => 0.0000
                    [row_weight] => 0
                    [product_type] => simple
                    [price_incl_tax] => 10
                    [base_price_incl_tax] => 10
                    [row_total_incl_tax] => 10
                    [base_row_total_incl_tax] => 10
                    [discount_tax_compensation_amount] => 0
                    [base_discount_tax_compensation_amount] => 0
                    [free_shipping] => 
                    [qty_options] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [product (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor)] => Array
                        (
                            [entity_id] => 3
                            [attribute_set_id] => 4
                            [type_id] => simple
                            [sku] => test
                            [has_options] => 0
                            [required_options] => 0
                            [created_at] => 2018-03-12 15:09:32
                            [updated_at] => 2018-03-12 15:13:51
                            [price] => 10.0000
                            [weight] => 0.0000
                            [name] => test
                            [url_key] => test
                            [gift_message_available] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [visibility] => 4
                            [tax_class_id] => 2
                            [request_path] => test.html
                            [tier_price] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [tier_price_changed] => 0
                            [store_id] => 1
                            [customer_group_id] => 0
                        )

                    [tax_class_id] => 2
                    [has_error] => 
                    [converted_price] => 10
                    [base_original_price] => 10.0000
                    [base_calculation_price] => 10
                    [tax_calculation_item_id] => sequence-1
                    [tax_calculation_price] => 10
                    [base_tax_calculation_price] => 10
                    [discount_calculation_price] => 10
                    [base_discount_calculation_price] => 10
                )

        )

    [dest_country_id] => IT
    [dest_region_code] => Stato/Provincia
    [dest_street] => Indirizzo
    [dest_city] => Città
    [dest_postcode] => 00000
    [package_value] => 10
    [package_value_with_discount] => 10
    [package_weight] => 0
    [package_qty] => 1
    [package_physical_value] => 10
    [free_method_weight] => 0
    [store_id] => 1
    [website_id] => 1
    [free_shipping] => 
    [base_currency (Magento\Directory\Model\Currency)] => Array
        (
            [currency_code] => EUR
        )

    [package_currency (Magento\Directory\Model\Currency)] => Array
        (
            [currency_code] => EUR
        )

    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 10
    [country_id] => US
    [region_id] => 12
    [postcode] => 90034
)
```

The only fields from Shipping address are:

```
[dest_country_id] => IT
[dest_region_code] => Stato/Provincia
[dest_street] => Indirizzo
[dest_city] => Città
[dest_postcode] => 00000
```

because they're needed to calculate shipping rates.
So, unless your field affects shipping costs, you don't need it in $request object.

Comment: But I need custom attribute value if mob_type == local set cost - $5 else $8.

Comment: That's why I need custom attribute value on request object