# How to save value to customer attributes from checkout page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, savedata

I have created a customer attribute which created dynamically from backend its fine works in customer_account_create and customer_account_edit and I  stuck at saving customer attribute field data in after saving address information in the checkout form.  After  filling shipping address, shipping and press next button method I m getting the following error

message: "Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5d3aa1ebbf82a"

**Exception log:** **'Report ID: webapi-5d3aa1ebbf82a; Message: Property "TestAge" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface".' in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor**

and I followed [**this link**](https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/)

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cm__fields_layoutprocessor" xsi:type="object">Cm\CustomerAttribute\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/ Cm/CustomerAttribute/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Block\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    protected $customerSession;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(\Cm\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession)
    {
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        $jsLayout
    ) {
        $attributeCollection = $this->helper->getUserDefinedAttribures();

       if ($attributeCollection->getSize() > 0) 
       {
         foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute)

         {
        if ($this->helper->isAttribureForCheckoutRegister($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
        {
        $frontEndLabel = $attribute->getStoreLabel($this->helper->getStoreId());

        $customAttributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
      if($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

        $customerId =$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
         $customer =$this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        $customerAttr = $customer->getCustomAttribute($customAttributeCode)->getValue();
        }
        else
        {
          $customerAttr = NULL;
        }
        $fieldRequiredClass = ($attribute->getIsRequired()) ? 'true' : '' ;
        if($fieldRequiredClass == '')
        {
            $fieldRequiredClass = false;
        }
        $fieldFrontendClass = ($attribute->getFrontendClass()) ? $attribute->getFrontendClass() : '';
        $fieldInput =$attribute->getFrontendInput();
        $attributeId = $attribute->getAttributeId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $attributeOptionAll = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection::class)
                                    ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                                    ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                                    ->setStoreFilter()
                                    ->load();
        $opt_val = array();
        $allOptions=array();


        foreach ($attributeOptionAll->getData() as $key => $v) 
        {
          // $allid = $v['attribute_id'];
          $opt_val['value'] = $v['option_id'];
          $opt_val['label'] = $v['value'];
          $allOptions[] = $opt_val;
      }
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $this->addNewField($customAttributeCode,$frontEndLabel, $fieldRequiredClass,  $fieldFrontendClass,$fieldInput,  $allOptions, $customerAttr );

        }
      }
    }
    return $jsLayout;
    }

    private function addNewField($customAttributeCode, $frontEndLabel, $fieldRequiredClass,  $fieldFrontendClass, $fieldInput, $allOptions, $customerAttr  )
    {
        if($fieldInput == 'text')
        {
            $fieldInputType = 'input';
            $fieldAbstract =  'abstract';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'date') {
           $fieldInputType = 'date'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'date';
        }
        elseif ($fieldInput == 'select') {
           $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'select';
        }

        elseif ($fieldInput == 'boolean') {
           $fieldInputType = 'select'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'select';
           $allOptions = [
                 ['value' => '0', 'label' => 'No'],
                 ['value' => '1', 'label' => 'Yes']
               ];

        }
         elseif ($fieldInput == 'textarea') {
           $fieldInputType = 'textarea'; 
           $fieldAbstract =  'textarea';

        }
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/'.$fieldAbstract.'',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/'.$fieldInputType.'',
                'rows' => 5
                // 'tooltip' => [
                //     'description' => 'this is what the field is for',
                // ],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'label' => $frontEndLabel,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 1000,
            'validation' => [$fieldFrontendClass => true , 
                'required-entry' => $fieldRequiredClass],
            'options' =>  $allOptions,
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
            'value' => $customerAttr
        ];

         return $customField;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
 var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address': {
                'Cm_CustomerAttribute/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Cm_CustomerAttribute/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address': {
                'Cm_CustomerAttribute/js/action/create-shipping-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order': {
                'Cm_CustomerAttribute/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            },
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address': {
                'Cm_CustomerAttribute/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/web/js/action/create-shipping-address-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            if (messageContainer.custom_attributes != undefined) {
                $.each(messageContainer.custom_attributes , function( key, value ) {
                    messageContainer['custom_attributes'][key] = {'attribute_code':key,'value':value};
                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-billing-address-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setBillingAddressAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setBillingAddressAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var billingAddress = quote.billingAddress();

            if(billingAddress != undefined) {

                if (billingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                    billingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
                }

                if (billingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                    $.each(billingAddress.customAttributes, function (key, value) {

                        if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                            value = value['value'];
                        }

                        billingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;
                    });
                }

            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, wrapper,quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
        return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction, messageContainer) {

            var shippingAddress = quote.shippingAddress();

            if (shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] === undefined) {
                shippingAddress['extension_attributes'] = {};
            }

            if (shippingAddress.customAttributes != undefined) {
                $.each(shippingAddress.customAttributes , function( key, value ) {

                    if($.isPlainObject(value)){
                        value = value['value'];
                    }

                    shippingAddress['customAttributes'][key] = value;
                    shippingAddress['extension_attributes'][key] = value;

                });
            }

            return originalAction(messageContainer);
        });
    };
});
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/etc/di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
         <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
         <plugin name="Cm_CustomerAttribute::ShippingInformationManagement" 
 type="Cm\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
          </type>
      </config>
```

> app/code/Cm/CustomerAttribute/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
   <?php
    namespace Cm\CustomerAttribute\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

  class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
     protected $helper;
     protected $quoteRepository;
     public function __construct(

    \Bootsgrid\CustomerAttribute\Helper\Customerattribute $helper,
     \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {

        $this->helper = $helper;
         $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }


    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
       $extensionAttributes = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
       $custAttributes = $extensionAttributes->getExtensionAttributes();
       if($custAttributes )
       {
         $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);


        $customField = $custAttributes->getTestTextarea();
        $cus = $custAttributes->getTestAge();
        $quote->setTestAge($cus);
        $quote->setTestTextarea($customField);



      }
        // error_log(print_r($custAttributes,1));
    }
}
```

How to save the customer_field  dynamically in sales_order and quote order in magento 2

image:

[image]
**When using extension_attributes.xml file its saved into  db but i want to pass a  attribute_code dynamically in the xml file**

> etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="test_age" type="string" /> \* how to pass "test_age" dynamically *\
        <attribute code="test_textarea" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

[image]

Comment: what a dynamic customer attributes?! you literlly posted us some code and a screenshot. how are we supposed to help

Comment: @philipp Sander   apologies for the improper post and  i m  update a post now. Please  verify the above edited post

Comment: what are "dynamic customer attributes" there is no such thing in magento

Comment: What error  have you faced?

Comment: @philipp Sander   i was created  a custom attributes  field dynamically from backend    refer [this extension](https://amasty.com/customer-attributes-for-magento-2.html) i  was try to done like a this extension

Comment: its reflect a [console error](http://prnt.sc/odxzku) @ChiragPatel

Comment: which is your custom attribute in the given image?

Comment: @Rajeev please check my edited image

Comment: Can you please post save logic in your question to investigate?

Comment: i have not done  a save logic

Comment: Do you have an option to register a customer in checkout page?

Comment: yes i have customer_attributes in register page

Comment: wait  i will postmy code

Comment: No i'm asking about....do you have option for customer to register in checkout page....when placing an order?

Comment: I had similar issue and I tried https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/ Solution and worked fine 
I added my attributes in xml file and worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is when the page is loaded your custom field is not added means it is undefined and that is why that field value length is not getting. That is why it's occurred error.

Just you will and the condition in your js file. (when field length code is written.)

```
if (typeof [field] === "undefined") {
 // after your actually code
}
```

Let me know if you still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've yet to add the mixin for saving data to the server. Have a look at [Magento Devdocs - here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html)

You are done with step 1. Start from Step 2 and you should be able to save your field. Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: i was done a step 2 also its not saved in the quote

Comment: Please post your entire code. Did you create the mixin? What error are you getting?

Comment: i was post my code. please check a edited question in above

Comment: Are you getting something in the error logs from the plugin?

Comment: Hello... what if this is a custom step? how can I save the data when `Next` button is pressed? I have not found any solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my question and answer seems like that.

[Shipping address custom attribute value not display in address box in magento2.2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216191/shipping-address-custom-attribute-value-not-display-in-address-box-in-magento2-2)

[Shipping address custom attribute value not getting in RateRequest object in Carrier Model in magento2.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219654/shipping-address-custom-attribute-value-not-getting-in-raterequest-object-in-car)

please check all the answers. Let me know if you still issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) of Magento DevDocs.
You need to add mixin and define your attributes in **extension_attributes.xml** file so you can access and save your custom attribute's value.